# Uploading existing sketch via Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

i have a Arduino which is connected to my PC. I'm sending some hex values over Serial port (with Python/Spyder IDE) to it to control the GPIO pins.
Is there a way to upload the sketch to the Arduino without using the IDE. 
I don't want to write the sketch in python. Just want to upload a existing sketch via a Python script.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build and upload Arduino sketches with python, there are two worthwhile tools: [build_arduino.py](http://playground.arduino.cc/BuildArduino/Py) and [arduino-sketch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/arduino-sketch/0.2).

Their pages provide detailed installation and usage instructions.